# Можно ли sql-запросом найти группу записей с разными значениями по всем полям

Tags: sql

Исходные данные(таблица в прикреплении) + нужны группы с количеством 4-е(для данной размерности), у которых нет повторов по одним и тем же полям. Тут может быть ТОЛЬКО две такие группы(получены просто циклом): 1-я [1,3,2,3], [2,1,5,2], [3,4,3,6], [4,2,6,5] и 2-я [1,2,3,2], [2,4,2,5], [3,1,6,3], [4,3,5,6], у которых нет повтора по одному и тому же полю(или при одном и том же индексе для соответствующих массивов). Т.е., если я делаю просто select distinct row1, row2, row3, row4 from four, то, конечно, я получу все 16 записей, т.к. если брать по ВСЕМ 4-м полям, то тут нет повторов, но, мне нужно было бы что-то наподобие select distinct row1, distinct row2, distinct row3, distinct row4 from four(т.е. distinct как бы по каждому полю ОТДЕЛЬНО), но, как я понимаю, такого не бывает? Или возможен какой-то другой подход?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. возможен ли тут sql-запрос, который бы давал результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...или
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

...тут дамп для таблицы
[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://sqlize.online/s/zH)

Comment: join таблицы с самой собой по условию `A.row1 != B.row1 and A.row2 != B.row2 and ...`

Comment: Спасибо Mike, но я, конечно же, пробовал это - SELECT *      
FROM four as t1, four as t2 
WHERE t1.row1<>t2.row1 and t1.row2<>t2.row2 and t1.row3<>t2.row3 and t1.row4<>t2.row4
что даст решение на том небольшом примере(4 массива), что я привел, но если взять больше массивов(я прикрепил другую картинку), я не уверен, что получу необходимый результат, используя такой select

Comment: *я не уверен, что получу необходимый результат, используя такой select* И какие же резоны позволяют сомневаться?

Comment: Если результат такого запроса отличается от ожиданий, значит ожидания отличаются от описанного в вопросе

Comment: ...я думаю, не совсем корректно сформулировал задачу, сорри, поправил

Comment: Боюсь, эта задача точно не для SQL.

Comment: это задача поиска клики в графе. решается иерархическим запросом.  конечно, только для небольших таблиц

Comment: вот посмотрите как реализован чем-то похожий алгоритм с графами https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1537305/529431 (похожесть алгоритмов в необходимости перебора вершин/рёбер графа с некоторыми ограничениями)

Comment: @ESkri, поясните, пожалуйста, как эта таблица описывает граф.

Comment: строки таблицы - вершины графа.  рёбра проводим между каждой парой вершин (t1 и t2), для которых `t1.row1<>t2.row1 and t1.row2<>t2.row2 and t1.row3<>t2.row3 and t1.row4<>t2.row4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю примерно так через SQL

```
SELECT * FROM four as t1
inner join four as t2 on t1.row1<>t2.row1 and t1.row2<>t2.row2
   and t1.row3<>t2.row3 and t1.row4<>t2.row4 
   and t2.id>t1.id
inner join four as t3 on t1.row1<>t3.row1 and t1.row2<>t3.row2
   and t1.row3<>t3.row3 and t1.row4<>t3.row4 
   and t2.row1<>t3.row1 and t2.row2<>t3.row2
   and t2.row3<>t3.row3 and t2.row4<>t3.row4 
   and t3.id>t2.id
inner join four as t4 on t1.row1<>t4.row1 and t1.row2<>t4.row2
   and t1.row3<>t4.row3 and t1.row4<>t4.row4 
   and t2.row1<>t4.row1 and t2.row2<>t4.row2
   and t2.row3<>t4.row3 and t2.row4<>t4.row4 
   and t3.row1<>t4.row1 and t3.row2<>t4.row2
   and t3.row3<>t4.row3 and t3.row4<>t4.row4 
   and t4.id>t3.id 
order by t1.id
```

Результат такой:

| id1 | r.1 | r.2 | r. | r.4 | id2 | r.1 | r.2 | r.3 | r.4 | id3 | r.1 | r.2 | r.3 | r.4 | id4 | r.1 | r.2 | r.3 | r.4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 9 | 3 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 15 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 12 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 6 | 14 | 4 | 2 | 6 | 5 |

Сокращенно, нагляднее, только Id строк

| Id1 | Id2 | Id3 | Id4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 | 9 | 15 |
| 3 | 5 | 12 | 14 |

Comment: ValNik - спасибо, это работает. Правда, если размерность будет расти, придется добавлять join-ы. Жаль, конечно, что не может быть что-то типа select distinct row1, distinct row2, distinct row3, distinct row4 from four

Comment: Да, придется добавлять. Но размерность зависит больше от размера таблицы, будет расти умеренно - подойдет)